# Can I zero the gauge on my floor pump

Tags: pump

I ordered a zefal husky pump, and it just arrived today. I am pretty excited about it. (Who doesn't get excited about pumps?)

The downside is that the gauge is reading ~50psi instead of ~0psi I wouldn't mind if it was off by 5psi or so, but this is ridiculous. Is there a way to fix it, or do I have to return it?

Comment: Hard to say.  Some gauges are adjusted by twisting the gauge body, some are supposedly "factory sealed".  But I'd bet you have the former.

Comment: Like @DanielRHicks said you might be able to rotate the gauge (silly question, are there 2 hands on the gauge? maybe the one pointing to 50 is the "target" hand?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong and managed to fix it. It was a minor enough issue that I'm not going to return the pump.

[image: zefal husky pressure gauge]

As shown in the image above, the pressure gauge is protected by a plastic cover. It's pretty easy to slide this cover up the shaft of the pump and out of the way.

Once this is out of the way, the pressure gauge can be removed by unscrewing it counter-clockwise.

The problem is that the needle on the gauge can become loose and point to the wrong value even when there is no pressure.  Firstly check if the needle is loose, re-adjust to zero and re-secure the needle by applying some downward pressure.  If this doesn't work, a little pull on the needle should release it from its pin, rotate back to zero and secure the needle back into place.

Once it has been re-zeroed, you can screw the gauge back on and slide the protective cover back. Then you're done.

Comment: Also shown in the photo is the normal "stop" for the indicator hand at the zero position. That way, when there's zero pressure, the indicator rests against the stop. Do you re-zero the gauge so that the indicator is just barely touching the stop?

Answer (score 4):

At least two reviews on Amazon for this particular pump report problems with the gauge, so I think you probably need to return it for replacement.

Before you send it back, though, try DanielRHicks's suggestion to twist the gauge body. In a quick search, I wasn't able to find out whether this particular pump has an adjustable gauge, but it's worth a try.

Comment: Thanks for looking up those reviews. Nice to know it's a standard problem. I did figure out how to fix it though.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to fix it. Hopefully the pin isn't likely to get stuck again.